# Stuck with medRV in highfrequency package

Tags: r

I am trying to get the daily medRV of 5 minutes interval from my data (1 year data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Cg2ZU8af3Y1aaHK5QVVbz8rguE3d8ZHq) for the timespan from 8/1/2014 to 2/1/2015.

However, I got an error after I entered the medRV function:

```
head(pricedata)
Datetime    Price  
   1) 2014-01-08 06:35:00 41710.82    
   2) 2014-01-08 06:40:00 41685.84    
   3) 2014-01-08 06:45:00 41699.24    
   4) 2014-01-08 06:50:00 41683.68    
   5) 2014-01-08 06:55:00 41645.51    
   6) 2014-01-08 07:00:00 41682.11

tail(pricedata)        
Datetime    Price   
1) 2014-12-31 12:50:00  4151.00   
2) 2014-12-31 12:55:00  4151.00   
3) 2014-12-31 13:00:00  4151.00   
4) 2015-01-02 06:35:00 41710.82   
5) 2015-01-02 06:40:00 41685.84    
6) 2015-01-02 06:45:00 41699.24  

library(highfrequency)  
medrv = medRV( rdata = pricedata$Price, align.by ="minutes", align.period =5, makeReturns=TRUE)
```

> Error in seq.default(start(ts), end(ts), by = tby) :    'from' must be
>   of length 1>

As I tried using the medRV function using the artificial data in `highfrequency` package, namely the `sample_5minprices`, it can provides me the daily medRV of 5 minutes interval for the whole month.

I have no idea what to do with the

> Error in seq.default(start(ts), end(ts), by = tby) : 
>     'from' must be of length 1>

Appreciate if anyone can enlighten me on this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what is seq.default but I just found out that I have to convert my data.frame into a xts format, and then the function medRV can run well.